# Qt creator- class does not name a type

Tags: qt5

I using qt creator 3.0.1 while building it shows MainWindow has not been declared
I tried changing order of #include statements but no luck.
code that gives error in function insert and display:

```
#ifndef WEATHER_H
#define WEATHER_H
#include "node.h"
#include "weather.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

#define NODE_H

class Weather
{
private:
    Node *head;
public:
    Weather();
    void insert(MainWindow *);
    void disp(MainWindow *);
};

#endif // WEATHER_H
```

my other header files:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "weather.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Weather *w;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

    class Node
    {
    private:
some variables

 friend class Weather;
    public:
        Node();
    };

    #endif // NODE_H
```

weather.h:

Comment: You don't need to include the header in your other headers, you can simply forward declare the types. This should help solve your problem.

Comment: can you explain exactly what I have to do? I'm new to Qt

Comment: It's not a Qt thing, it's a C++ thing. You should do some self research on the term "forward declaration C++"